# do i need to maintain a database for using push notification on my web server?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

how we can maintain push notification for hundreds of devices? do we need to maintain a database on server or apple will maintain this,we just need to send payload.also i'm confusing in this matter that how do i cancel already sent payload...does someone knows about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain your own database.  The payload that you send to Apple includes the device token of the iphone you are sending the message to.  Your table could contain as simple as an id for the user (auto-generated id, or email, or whatever you need), mapped to the iphone deviceToken, along with other columns and tables that you need for your book-keeping.  The device token can be stored as `String` for simplicity, but it's really a 32-byte BLOB.

Once you send a payload, you cannot cancel or check its status.  Once you send it, it's out of your hands.

Comment: can you please tell me a simple server side code to send payload from database.

Comment: also tell me how do send payload from my device to my server using objective-c

Comment: Top hit when googeling "PHP Apple Push Notification is "How to build an Apple Push Notification provider server (tutorial)" which is located at http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

I'd head on over to Urban Airship and play around with their implementation of Apple Push Notifications. They have a sample PHP application you can extend to fit your need and great step-by-step documentation on how to get your sample application up and running.

No, there is no way of canceling sent payload.